# Is --script a valid emacs switch?

Tags: script

When I execute

```
emacs --batch --script=/home/jim/test.el --no-site-file --file=testing
```

I get:

```
Cannot open load file: no such file or directory, /home/jim/--script=/home/jim/test.el
```

While `emacs --help` shows `--script` in its list of options, executing just
`emacs --script=test` junk
gives an error saying `--script` is not recognised.
Is there an alternative?

I'm using Emacs version 24.5.1.
Thanks
What is happening here?

Answer (score 5):

```
$ emacs --help
[...]
--file FILE             visit FILE
[...]
--script FILE               run FILE as an Emacs Lisp script
```

No `=` in either of those.

Try:

```
emacs --batch --script /home/jim/test.el --no-site-file --file testing
```

As for the actual error, that's a bit funky.  It seems to be deciding that the option *is* a `--script` option, and then using `--script=/home/jim/test.el` in its entirety as the script filename (and you are running it from your home directory, so that path gets prepended as well).

I suggest you <kbd>M-x</kbd> `report-emacs-bug` about that weirdness.

Comment: Not unless 26.1 has the same bug. 24.5.1 is *ancient*

Comment: I see that same behaviour in 26.1 and also in my build of 27.